# case-insensitive treeview sorting

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, case-insensitive

I am using below code to sort the treeview column but it is case sensitive i.e. if the column value is `[a,c,A]` the sorted value will be `[a,c,A]`but i want it as `[a,A,c]` and even the number sorting is only based on first digit i.e. if `[2,1,11]` is the column value, the output will be `[1,11,2]` what i want it to be as `[1,2,11]`. please help me with the idea to solve this issue. Thank you

```
for col in cols:
            self.treeview.heading(col, text=col,command=lambda c=col: self.sortby(self.treeview, c, 0))

def sortby(self,tree, col, descending):

            data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
            for child in tree.get_children('')]

            data.sort(reverse=descending)

            for ix, item in enumerate(data):
                tree.move(item[1], '', ix)

            tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: self.sortby(tree, col, \
                int(not descending)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case insensitive sorting is done by providing a key mapping function to sort.  For example, `sort(values, key=str.casefold)` (Python 3).

In the case of sorting over the first value of the tuple, the data sort line would become `data.sort(reverse=descending, key=lambda t: str.casefold(t[0]))`

Comment: Thank you.. but i am getting the following error : TypeError: descriptor 'casefold' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object. is there any option to do it for tuple, as the treeview value will be in tuple. @user650881

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you can set the key function to be a lambda that accesses the field of the tuple that should be used to sort over.  What field of the tuple do you want to sort by? @Kyle

Comment: The first value of the tuple. The output of the data is [('aa', 'I005'), ('A', 'I006')] i want to sort by first value. @user650881

Comment: @Kyle, that helped. I adjusted the answer to sort based on the first value of the tuple.  My answer churned a bit while I was updating as I looked at the Treeview api.

Comment: Thank you.. its working.. i am also facing issue with sorting numbers as well.. can you please help me with that. @user650881

Comment: @Kyle Try returning whatever comparable value you want to sort over. If it is a stringified number, you might need to convert it to a number.  If that doesn't seem to address the problem, perhaps you can provide an example.